# Python count the number of hours in each day from datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

From `dataframe` below, I want to count the number of hours in each single day. Each record weights 5 minutes. DateTime is TZ-aware.

```
Year    data
Timestamp                                       
2008-11-13 16:50:00+09:30   177.83
2008-11-13 16:55:00+09:30   165.73
2008-11-15 17:00:00+09:30   160.34
2008-11-15 17:15:00+09:30   148.90
2008-11-15 17:40:00+09:30   113.66
2008-11-20 17:15:00+09:30   121.12
2008-11-20 17:20:00+09:30   109.55
2008-11-20 17:35:00+09:30   100.86
2008-11-20 17:50:00+09:30   90.72
2008-11-20 07:55:00+09:30   86.27
```

The expected result is

```
Year    hrs/day
Timestamp                                       
2008-11-13 00:00:00+09:30   0.16666666666666666 # <-- 10 min / 60   
2008-11-15 00:00:00+09:30   0.25                # <-- 15 min / 60
2008-11-20 00:00:00+09:30   0.4166666666666667  # <-- 15 min / 60
```

This is what I did.

```
df['Hour'] = df.index.hour.astype(int)
days = df.resample('D').apply({'Hour':'count'})
```

which gives me a column 'Hour' with values are the number of record per day.

Next...

```
days['Hr/dy'] = (days['Hour'] * 5.0)/60.0
```

where '5.0' is the timestamp interval. With this way, I can get the expected result.

But, I must switch between many data frames with different timestamp intervals. Providing the interval one-by-one every time I switch to a new data is not convenient. I need to get the timestamp interval automatically from the timestamp index.

`freqdays = pd.infer_freq(df.index[0:10])`
gives a non integer timestamp frequency ('5T') whis is not usable for mathematical operations to further get the hours.

What I need is either:
- a method to get the frequency (interval) from the timestamp index in integer or float, or
- to calculate the length of hours per day directly from the timestamp index.

**Edit**:
The original data has 5 minute interval with many missing records. The start and end hour is different from day to day.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your problem. For `2008-11-15` you have a 15 minute interval and then a 25 minute interval (40 minutes total). Why do you get 0.25 hours? Shouldn't it be 0.67 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to get the minimum difference in seconds in your index with:

```
print (df.index.to_series(keep_tz=True).sort_values().diff().min().total_seconds())
300.0
```

so to get your result, do the groupby per day, multiply by the min difference of index, and divide by 3600 to get in hours:

```
df_agg = df.groupby(df.index.date).count()\
           *df.index.to_series(keep_tz=True).sort_values().diff().min().total_seconds()/3600
print (df_agg)

                date
2008-11-13  0.166667
2008-11-15  0.250000
2008-11-20  0.416667
```